# difference between redirect and redirect inside modelandview

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In spring controller class to redirect to a url

- some places  all using `return "redirect:/abc.htm";`.
- also using `return new ModelAndView("redirect:/abc.htm")`.

Any one please explain the difference and similarities of both statements.

And in which situation it has to use.

---

Rohit:

Am using RedirectAttribute to get values from old url.
In this case am getting value while using this `return "redirect:/abc.htm";` 
but not in this  `return new ModelAndView("redirect:/abc.htm")`.
Is there any difference in `RedirectAttributes`

Comment: Both of them do the same job. Returning `ModelAndView` is old way which existed before Spring 2.0.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The statements:

```
return "redirect:/abc.htm"
return new ModelAndView("redirect:/abc.htm")
```

do the same thing: `redirects` the request to `abc.htm`. If a view name is returned that has the
prefix `redirect:`, this is recognized as a special indication that a redirect is needed. The rest of the view name will be treated as the redirect URL.

With the statement

```
return "redirect:/abc.htm"
```

you can only return the redirect view name.

With `ModelAndView` you can return both `model` and `view` in a single return value:

```
ModelAndView modelAndView =  new ModelAndView("redirect:/abc.htm");
modelAndView.addObject("modelAttribute" , new ModelAttribute());
return modelAndView;
```

But the attribute value will not be available in the new redirect request that the client(browser) will make for the URL `/abc.htm`. The best use of `ModelAndView` is when you forward the request to a new URL, so that you can return both `model` and `view` together in a single return value. For redirect scenarios, if you want to pass attributes, you should use `RedirectAttributes`.