# Redirect to an API that has @RequestBody arguments

Tags: java, spring-boot, redirect, modelandview

The below API is called from the UI, as well as it wants to be redirected to, by other APIs.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showAbc", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView showAbc(@RequestBody Abc abcInstance) {
    //doSomething
}
```

The below API is also called from the UI end, but it fetches an instance of Abc class using a repository call and now wants to call the above API using redirect, and also wants to pass the instance as an argument.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showBcd", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView showBcd(@RequestParam String bcdId){
    Abc abc = abcRepository.findByBcdId(bcdId);
    /* How to pass the instance of Abc, when redirecting to /showAbc */
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/showAbc");
}
```

Now, in the above redirect I also want to pass the instance of Abc, when redirecting  to /showAbc from /showBcd.

Comment: What you're trying to do looks not correct for me. The first method should be triggered on `POST /showAbc` and the second one with redirect never do that. There is no POST request I would say.

Comment: Please add controller like `redirect:/controller/showAbc`

Comment: @john so r u saying, that we cannot redirect to a POST method?

Comment: @DeedarAliBrohi the redirection is fine, I want to know, how can I pass the arguments?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing model attribute during redirect in spring MVC and avoiding the same in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301114/passing-model-attribute-during-redirect-in-spring-mvc-and-avoiding-the-same-in-u)

Comment: @MehrajMalik Nope, I'm not sure the Annotation @ RequestBody will interfere in this or not, if I pass a flash attributes, I've to get the attribute from a flashMap, under Redirect Attributes.
But this API is also getting fired from the UI, where the Abc Instance is required as a Request Body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend calling one API to another if it's in the same application. This way you are tightly coupling API to API. Either leave the API contract to be called to  UI or handle the delegation via plain java service calls.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showAbc", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView showAbc(@RequestBody Abc abcInstance) {
    return new ModelAndView("abc",abcService.get());
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/showBcd", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView showBcd(@RequestParam String bcdId){
    // You should move this repo call to bcdService.java
    Abc abc = abcRepository.findByBcdId(bcdId);
    //Use a normal service call to get the instance instead of a API call
    return new ModelAndView("abc",abcService.getViaInstance(abc));
}
```

However, to have a model passed to the view(**Forward the request**), you need to add to the model as :

```
ModeAndView m = new ModelAndView("forward:/showAbc");
Abc abc = getAbcInstance();
m.addObject("abc",abc);
return m;
```

Comment: Awesome !! This helped a lot, would be following the same!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
ModeAndView m = new ModelAndView("redirect:/showAbc");
Abc abc = abcRepository.findByBcdId(bcdId);
m.addObject("abc",abc);
return m;
```

Comment: does this actually work? According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19517202/365237), it doesn't

Comment: @eis Yup. Request has to be forwarded can't be redirected to achieve this.

Comment: yes. forwarding and redirecting are quite different things.